# How to solve a NaN error?

Tags: javascript

I queried about this problem the other day but didn't include enough code. I'm basically getting a NaN error in **JavaScript**, with my mic input signal being displayed between -36 and 'NaN'. I understand it means 'not a number' but I'm not sure how to fix it. Below I've added my code, and the code from the function of 'getValue' within the **Tone.js** framework.

My code:

```
function checkLevel() {

    var linearLevel = levelMeter.getValue();
    var minLeveldB = Tone.gainToDb(0.0000761);
    var maxLeveldB = Tone.gainToDb(0.0157895);

    var leveldB = Tone.gainToDb(linearLevel);
    var absoluteLevel = Math.abs(leveldB);

    if (leveldB < minLeveldB) {
        leveldB = minLeveldB;
    }

    if (leveldB > maxLeveldB) {
        leveldB = maxLeveldB;
    }

    var n = leveldB.toFixed(0); // Rounds input signal down to 0 decimal places

    if (ISMICOPEN) {
        console.log(n); // Logs the rounded number to the console
    }

    decibelMeter.innerText = n; // Displays the input on the screen
}
window.setInterval(checkLevel, 700);
```

Where levelMeter is a new Tone.js meter instance and decibelMeter is a span in HTML to display the signal.

Tone.js getValue() code:

```
 /**
     *  Get the signal value of the incoming signal
     *  @returns {Number}
     */
    Tone.Meter.prototype.getValue = function () {
        this._analyser.type = 'waveform';
        var value = this._analyser.getValue();
        return value[0];
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which variable is getting `NaN`, and where in the code are you seeing this? My guess is it's coming from `gainToDb()`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm seeing -36 which is the maxLeveldB, so I'm guessing it must be the minLeveldB that is showing a NaN error.

The gainToDb() function looks like:

Tone.gainToDb = function (gain) {
         return 20 * (Math.log(gain) / Math.LN10);
     };

Comment: High school math: You can't take the log of a negative number.

Comment: `Math.log()` returns `NaN` if the argument is negative.

Comment: @Barmar but I'm taking the log of a positive number (0.0000761) which is roughly equal to -82, so the answer is negative but the number i'm taking the log of is positive.

Comment: What's the value of `linearLevel`?

Comment: Where are you seeing NaN?

Comment: @Barmar linearLevel is the linear value (0-1) before it's converted to decibels, decibelMeter is displaying NaN depending on the incoming signal value

Comment: Which variable is getting set to NaN, and when is this happening? Use the Javascript debugger to single-step through the code to see when it happens.

Comment: @Barmar I see now, when the linearLevel is negative, leveldB is attempting to convert to decibels using log but is unable to. The linearLevel should only be going between 0-1 so I'm not sure why this has happened.

Comment: @Barmar saying that, getValue is used for an analyser which would go between -1 and +1 so maybe I am using the wrong function, or need to scale it.